# Does new Android API includes all previous version API?

Tags: android, eclipse, api, adt, eclipse-adt

This may be a noob question as i am new to Android development.

So i downloaded **ADT** and when i started **SDK Manager** it threw me a long list of Android APIs; i installed the latest API but i got confused as i don't know if i only install **API  20** will i get full Android API or specific to that version/release?

**For example:** I downloaded API for KitKat so i get the full API with all the classes and interfaces? or only the new ones that are introduced in KitKat?

Comment: It should tagged as discussion

Comment: If you have installed Api 19 then you get all the api specific to that version and you can code only for devices with api 19, if you want lower version then you have to madatorily install other versions too

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :)
But if i want lower versions to support my app i can set the build target to lower versions!

Comment: Yes you can set with min sdk and max sdk version in manifest files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download API 20, you will get all the API's that are available to the level 20. It means you will get the new features, AND all the apis that are required to develop for devices running level 20.

**It does not mean that you will only get the updates** 
Some features might be deprecated in a newer version. That means if a particular function has been changed, you will get updated version in the respective level.

Comment: OK, so i will get the new features in API 20 and if some features/classes are common in API 19 & 20; i will get those features in API 20 right? no need to separately download API 19?

Comment: yes, you will get everything of 19 unless its a new feature only available in 20. You dont need to download 19

Answer (score 0):

It will give you a latest API, but if any feature are been diprecated, they won't be included in them. But for startup purpose its no stuffs to worry about having only one API installed.

refer the below link:-
[Android API References](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)